# Handling an html web form through android

Tags: android, asp.net, webforms, http-post

I am trying to submit a webform programmatically though android, where the user will input details into editText fields and then press a submit button.

The webform is at http://www.clarecoco.ie/your-council/voting/register-to-vote/check-the-register/default.aspx

If someone can , have a look at the form and check what details i would need to create a HTTPpost with a list of nameValuePairs.

I have no idea how i would find out the query string that is created when the submit button is pressed on the website so i could build the HTTPpost on the device.

The web form itself is handled using aspx which makes a difference but i dont know what difference.

cheers

Comment: do you have to post to that form or do you have acces to the code of the website and could create your own received page?

Comment: no access to code, i have to post to that form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FireBug to get the post detail. Here is the post detail for one of the test request made.

```
  __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJNzU5NjU4OTU5D2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIJD2QWAgIBD2QWBgIBDxAPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQWAGQCAg8PFgIfAGhkZAIFDw8WAh8AaGRkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQxJbWFnZUJ1dHRvbjLvm8lSjd8gJEmQ4R5YBFMv1q%2BvKw%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBgLQgdW3BwKKqdGpBwK5h62pDwKk4fXkBgLqorHhCwLSwtXkAjU7OzYKwCKL8cD6WdPrSzfMPeFS&txtSurname=testSurname&txtFirstName=testFirstName&txtHouseNumber=1&txtTownland=Dublin&ImageButton2.x=62&ImageButton2.y=13
```

Comment: how do use firebug to find this using chrome

Comment: There is a built-in module in chrome to do the same work as firebug (press F12). you can also download firebug for Chrome from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench

Comment: i will do, just when i retrieve this information it is encoded like this `/wEPDwUJNzU5NjU4OTU5D2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWBAIJD2QWAgIBD2QWCmYPDxYEHgRUZXh0BQRnZHNkHgdWaXNpYmxlaGR==`  what is the encoding of your above answer

Comment: That is the value of viewstate which you might not need. Things you need are     `txtSurname=testSurname&txtFirstName=testFirstName&txtHouseNumber=1&txtTownland=Dublin`

Comment: it needs to be sent also..something to do with asp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4921/discussion-between-molleman-and-junaid)